# Lost on how to do item removed from cart

Tags: vb.net

So I have to do a shopping cart program and I have it don't for the most part but I am having trouble figuring out how i would deal with items being remove from cart?
An advice on how I would work with is would be appreciated

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim subTotal As Decimal
    Dim tax As Decimal
    Dim itemCount As Integer
    Dim shipping As Integer
    Dim total As Decimal



    Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub IDidItYourWay1195ToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles IDidItYourWay1195ToolStripMenuItem.Click
        shoppingLB.Items.Add("I Did It Your Way $11.95")
        subTotal = subTotal + 11.95
        itemCount = itemCount + 1
    End Sub

    Private Sub TheHistoryOfScotland1450ToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TheHistoryOfScotland1450ToolStripMenuItem.Click
        shoppingLB.Items.Add("The History of Scotland $14.50")
        subTotal = subTotal + 14.5
        itemCount = itemCount + 1
    End Sub

    Private Sub LearnCalculusInOneDay2995ToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LearnCalculusInOneDay2995ToolStripMenuItem.Click
        shoppingLB.Items.Add("Learn Calculus in One Day $29.95")
        subTotal = subTotal + 29.95
        itemCount = itemCount + 1
    End Sub

    Private Sub FeelTheStress1850ToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FeelTheStress1850ToolStripMenuItem.Click
        shoppingLB.Items.Add("Feel the Stress $18.50")
        subTotal = subTotal + 18.5
        itemCount = itemCount + 1
    End Sub

    Private Sub LearnCalculusInOneDay2995ToolStripMenuItem1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LearnCalculusInOneDay2995ToolStripMenuItem1.Click
        shoppingLB.Items.Add("Learn Calculus in One Day $29.95")
        subTotal = subTotal + 29.95
        itemCount = itemCount + 1
    End Sub

    Private Sub TheHistoryOfScotland1450ToolStripMenuItem1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TheHistoryOfScotland1450ToolStripMenuItem1.Click
        shoppingLB.Items.Add("The History of Scotland $14.50")
        subTotal = subTotal + 14.5
        itemCount = itemCount + 1
    End Sub

    Private Sub TheScienceOfBodyLanguage1295ToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TheScienceOfBodyLanguage1295ToolStripMenuItem.Click
        shoppingLB.Items.Add("The Science of Body Language $12.95")
        subTotal = subTotal + 12.95
        itemCount = itemCount + 1
    End Sub

    Private Sub RelaxationTechniques1150ToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RelaxationTechniques1150ToolStripMenuItem.Click
        shoppingLB.Items.Add("Relaxation Techniques $11.50")
        subTotal = subTotal + 11.5
        itemCount = itemCount + 1
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        shipping = itemCount * 2
        tax = subTotal * 0.06
        total = subTotal + tax + shipping
        taxTxt.Text = FormatCurrency(tax)
        shippingTxt.Text = FormatCurrency(shipping)
        subTxt.Text = FormatCurrency(subTotal)
        totalTxt.Text = FormatCurrency(total)
    End Sub

    Private Sub removeBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles removeBtn.Click

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Option A) Use the ToolStringItems as checked items so you can add or remove depending on the check state. Option B) Make the app Object Oriented and add an Item Class {ItemName, Price} which gets added to the cart so you can find and remove them later (as well as easily update the costs).

Comment: so for option b I do a class for each item and the add that class to the listbox and then check the classes within the list box and grab the price from that object?

Comment: You wouldnt "do a class for each item" you'd define a class which could describe *any* item.  The shopping cart is then a collection of them which would show in a ListBox or whatever

Comment: Might sound stupid but could I just do a for each loop and parse the price out of the listbox and calculate it that way?    Then in turn use the count of that loop to set the item count?

Comment: Is this a WinForms app or a web thing (toolstrip items are an odd presentation)

Comment: It's simpler then doing an entire separate form for the products and then managing passing it from one form to the other